# import svg-files from wxr - (upload works, import not)

Tags: import, xml, svg

Upload works  - Import from wxr not

We're updating several sites with a new page, imported from a wxr file.
Page, included form, jpg, png - all work fine but SVG not so much.

I've checked scripts that add svg to allowed mime, (`$mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';$mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg';` etc)

I've testet plugins (safeSvg, Disable Real MIME Check)

I've even added `define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );` into wp-config!

Same result - every time: "unable to import."

But regular upload works.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Hi Leif S., welcome to [wordpress.se]. Your question may need editing to get the best answers. As a quick guide, pretend you are talking to a busy colleague and have to tell them everything they absolutely need to give you a clear answer before they rush away. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution after a little more digging.

The problem lies in wordpress-importer

Found this from jan 30 on github:

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-importer/issues/47?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Then later the solution here:

https://www.playnicetogether.com/2015/11/07/wordpress-importer-plugin-content-length-problem-solved/

"the WordPress Importer plugin is not compatible with remote servers that use HTTP compression."

For WordPress v4.6 and above, please use the following:

```
add_filter( 'http_request_args', function( $r, $url ) { $r['headers']['Accept-Encoding'] = 'identity'; return $r; }, 10, 2 );
```

This solved the upload issue, and the plugin "SafeSvg" made the svg's show up in the media library.